# CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo", but CMake did not find one

Tags: cmake

I try build this khancyr/ardupilot_gazebo (github) plugin but I get this error after run `sudo cmake ..`
I use `fedora35` so I cant run `apt-get install libgazeboX-dev`
what can I do for this problem ?

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findgazebo.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo" with any
  of the following names:

    gazeboConfig.cmake
    gazebo-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gazebo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gazebo_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gazebo"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `apt-get update && apt-get install ros-foxy-gazebo-ros-pkgs` before running your command.